# Wrong Icon in Inbox message

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The icon for the message from careers is wrong! I double checked the company page and their logo is not remotely similar to 3D!

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

This is now fixed.

The API project references Stack Overflow in 6 files, most of them documentation. (e.g., [in the link in the first paragraph on the question type docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)).  These are done by appending the relative URL to a special "Stack Overflow" site, which resolves to the site where `SiteId == 1`.  The URL builder throws an NPE when that site is null, as it is for Stack Overflow Enterprise.

The Enterprise team resolved this by instead using the first main site in a lot of places where Stack Overflow was used.  Unfortunately, the logic wasn't first site by SiteId but first site alphabetically, so 3D Printing.

This affected inbox because items that are internally marked as coming from the still-existent-even-though-you-don't-see-it careers site are reassigned to Stack Overflow.

I've audited the original commit to revert the inbox issue and either point documentation links to point to appropriate place for a given build type or disappear if they aren't appropriate in the Enterprise context.